# Mootools 1.4.5 morph class not working

Tags: javascript, mootools

I've tried just about everything I can think of, and nothing seems to work.I'm trying to just do a simple class morph, but the class doesn't change and I have no idea why. There doesn't appear to be any errors, or at least as far as I can tell. Here's my code;

```
<div class="blue" id="bkg_color"></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {
        var en = new colorSwitcher();
    });

    var colorSwitcher= new Class({
        options: {
            author: 'Michael',
            version: '1.0',
            lastUpdate: '2014-04-22'
        },

        Implements: [Options,Events],
        initialize: function(options) {
            //Set main variables
            this.setOptions(options);

            //Get main objects
            this.bkgColor = $('bkg_color');

            //Run events
            this.setupActions();
        },

        setupActions: function() {
            $('bkg_color').morph('.green');    //doesnt work
            //this.bkgColor.morph('.green');   //doesnt work
            console.log(this.bkgColor);
        }
    });
</script>
```

The two classes simply change the background color. I can tell `setupActions` works and is called, because information for `this.bkgColor` appears in the console.

Testing was done in the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome, no results.

Comment: Works good for me. Can you post more code? you might be missing something in your CSS ? __http://jsfiddle.net/Lb872/__

Comment: @Sergio That's pretty much all there is for the javascript, and the css is literally `background-color:green` and `background-color:blue`. I've been doing various tests, and I just can't get it to work. I've been testing with some jsfiddles, and I can sometimes get it to work, but not always.

Comment: Did you __[see my jsFiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb872/)__ Is my fiddle the same as your code? if not, can you add your code missing in it?

Comment: @Sergio I think I may have found the problem. Styling for `.blue` and `.green` isn't at base level, the styles are nested further in.
ie. `body .box .blue` instead of just `.blue`

Comment: Well, for blue should't make a difference (check fiddle), but for green, if you are morphing to that class, it should be isolated. Anyway, you could pass the element in the options, like that your class would be more flexible (maybe there are better ways to do it): __http://jsfiddle.net/Lb872/3/__